# (Vue.js project) Webpack doesn't save favicon image to static folder on build

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I have the default Vue project with Webpack

`vue init webpack my-project`

---

I've put **favicon.png** into `src/assets` (as all my other images) and specified it in **index.html**:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/src/assets/favicon.png"/>
```

But after I've ran `npm run build` I don't see the favicon image in the static folder

---

#### Solutions from github:

[This answer](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot/issues/128#issuecomment-291639024) on github suggests that I have to do this:

In webpack.config.*.js files

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({   
    favicon: 'src/images/favicon.ico'
```

---

Is that how I should do it? Why is it so hard for webpack to save a favicon without you messing with config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, favicon files are in `static/img/icons` directory. You can change those files with yours. If you change a file name or extension, you should change corresponding file name in index.html, too.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you have to put in the `static/img`